# Python: Is there a way to count element occurrences for multidimensional numpy ndarrays row by row?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D array of values, and would like to count the occurrences of elements in each row. The `bincount` function only works on 1D arrays, and using python loops to loop through every row would not be ideal. The `unique` function has an argument return_counts, however, it counts entire columns, as opposed to the element by element basis for each row which I am looking for.
To illustrate this more clearly:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2],
              [2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3]])
print(a)
# [[1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2],
#  [2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3]]

b, c = np.unique(a, return_counts=True, axis=1) # Count elements in axis 1

print(b)
# [[1 1 2 2 3]
#  [2 3 3 5 4]]

print(c)
# [1 1 2 1 1]
```

Instead of counting elements in each row, `unique` counts the columns along the horizontal axis 1 which I specified; the column `[2, 3]` is counted twice while the others are counted once. Is there any way to achieve the behaviour I want using native numpy functions instead of python loops?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `numpy` has a good counter function. I suggest going with `collections.Counter()`, but it does add a for loop on the rows.

```
from collections import Counter
counts = [Counter(a[k, :]) for k in range(a.shape[0])]
```

The `Counter` object can be accessed with different methods, for instance `.most_common()`:

```
counts[0].most_common()
Out: [(2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1)]
```